# fetching links using re.findall

Tags: python

I'm trying to fetch all the links given in a file. All links are enclosed in "" and there are http,https and ftp links. Below is a sample output of the file.

```
$ cat file 

"http://www.google.com" and "http://www.yahoo.com" and "http://www.facebook.com"
"https://1.1.1.1" and "ftp://a.a.a.a"
```

**Below is my python code**

```
In [109]: FILE = open('file','r')

In [110]: data = FILE.read()

In [111]: links = re.findall('"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', data)

In [112]: print links

    [('http://www.google.com', 'http'), ('http://www.yahoo.com', 'http'), ('http://www.facebook.com', 'http'), ('https://1.1.1.1', 'http'), ('ftp://a.a.a.a', 'ftp')]
```

Why the output contains 'http' after the original link. Where did I go wrong?
Can someone please help. I'm using (IPython 2.3.1) in Python 2.7.6

Comment: Might have to do with capture groups. You have put parenthesis around `http|ftp`, which indicates an interest in the content matched by that subexpression, and thus it is returned, too. But I don't know python or the used regex-module, so take this with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your regex contain two capturing groups. 1st capturing group captures the whole link where the other captures only the `http`, `ftp` part. I suggest you to turn the second capturing group to non-capturing group since `re.findall` function gives the first preference to capturing groups. If no capturing group is found on the regex, then only it returns the matches.

```
re.findall(r'"((?:http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', data)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> s = '''"http://www.google.com" and "http://www.yahoo.com" and "http://www.facebook.com"
"https://1.1.1.1" and "ftp://a.a.a.a"'''
>>> re.findall(r'"((?:http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', s)
['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.facebook.com', 'https://1.1.1.1', 'ftp://a.a.a.a']
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your file looks like that you can split and strip:

```
lines=""""http://www.google.com" and "http://www.yahoo.com" and    "http://www.facebook.com"
"https://1.1.1.1" and "ftp://a.a.a.a"""

print([x.strip('"') for x in lines.split(" and ")])

['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.facebook.com"\n"https://1.1.1.1', 'ftp://a.a.a.a']
```

Comment: The file content is not exactly the same. But thanks for the trick :)